# Page Not found using routes codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have defined the page url in codeigniter e.g

```
$route['single_package/(:any)'] = 'dashboard/single_package/';
```

Now i have passed the encrypted id in url the url looks like

```
http://localhost/BgTravel/single_package/08b6a10d78fa89a3588423a5e5c688a2435e50228a277f4063869ea4c85b85f81575cfbd3ae0bbc73c2c5416e830599f7296bd9b1450c0681f111cd84f15b974fkwn56uExaGp1AHX88lbnvSdAaPEBYK3c2+bJu1MhO8=
```

Now the problem is that sometimes the page loads correctly showing all the data, sometimes it says page not found, i have used the encryption library to encrypt id, what should i do to avoid page not found errors.

Comment: Use a form button, pass the encrypted id in a hidden form field, and then you don't have to deal with the url issues.

Comment: You are not passing parameter in route. `$route['single_package/(:any)'] = 'dashboard/single_package/$1';`